# Can't remove Read-Only attribute in Windows 2003 Server

Tags: windows-server-2003

I've got a folder on a Windows 2003 R2 machine.  I uncheck the "read-only" checkbox option, tell it to apply to all subfolders, and click ok.

it appears to work, except when I check it again, the read-only checkbox remains checked.

I'm logged in as administrator, and I verified that I'm the owner of that folder and its contents.

What am I missing?

Comment: Probably duplicate.  Have a look at this question.  http://serverfault.com/questions/53187/unable-to-remove-read-only-attribute-from-folder-in-windows-xp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bug has been around since Win95 was released. i.e. The checkbox is checked regardless of the actual state of the attributes. Just ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

Are there hidden files or folders in the folder?  If so that could cause the check box to become rechecked.

Comment: I've had this happen to me as well.  It is well worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the attrib command to ensure the properties are set.

attrib /?

- to set properties, - to remove properties.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the Read-Only attribute via the DOS command proved to resolve my NFS permissions issue. (ie: attrib -r ) Thus, do NOT ignore the shaded Windows GUI checkbox that the folder is flagged Read-Only. "Windows" may not care, but Unix/AIX does!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issues and found it was related to the share permissions of the root directory, it was set to everyone read and therefore people could only read regardless of whether they had permission in the sub folders.